# Scroll in a WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, scroll

I tried to scroll in my WebView programaticly, but it does not work for me.
my code in .h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
IBOutlet WebView*browser;
}
```

and my code in .m:

```
- (IBAction)scrollAction:(id)sender {
[[[browser enclosingScrollView] contentView] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(40, 340)];
}
```

I make this app for Mac OS and not for iOS. If it helps, I wrote the same for iOS and that code worked there:

```
[browser.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(40, 340) animated:NO];
```

How can I do it, that when the button is pressed I jump to that point 40, 340?

Comment: scroll the scroll view itself, not its content view...

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you want to say. when I do it like this `[[[browser enclosingScrollView] browser] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(40, 340)];
}` it also doesn't work

Comment: no. Scroll [browser encolsingScrollView] itself, not anything else.

Comment: but I want to scroll TO 40, 340. and if I do it like this `[[browser enclosingScrollView] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0,0)];` there is also an issue

Comment: I believe user529758 means:  [[browser enclosingScrollView]  scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(40, 340)];